# Powershell: Password Must Change Next Logon when Password Expires in 1 day

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

Could someone help me with the following: I need a `PowerShell` script that searches a specific Organization Unit with a lot of users and sets: `Password must change @ next logon if the password expires within 1 day`.

I already have the following script:

```
$maxPwdAge=(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
$1day=(get-date).AddDays(1-$maxPwdAge).ToShortDateString()

Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * | where {($_.PasswordLastSet).ToShortDateString() -eq $1day} | select *
```

Answer (score 1):

You should instead compare `DateTime` objects directly, you plain don't need `ToShortDateString()` conversion to compare dates in Powershell. Also last `select *` is superfluous and only spoils the return type of an object.

```
$1day=(get-date).AddDays(1-$maxPwdAge)
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * |
where {$_.PasswordLastSet -ge $1day}
```

Should do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Can you modify the script so it shows all the users whose password expires tomorrow? @Vesper

Comment: Does it not show everyone that has less than 1 day until password expiration?

Comment: My fault, script works perfect! Thanks a lot!. Could you also help me with the following.. If there is a user that must change the password tomorrow then the check mark must be put in active directory: user must change password @ next logon @Vesper

Comment: This is a separate question, and it'll be better if you ask SO, not me directly.