# Powershell result must Set checkmark 'User must change Password'

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory, passwords

This  Powershell script shows the active directory users whose passwords expires tomorrow.

```
 $1day=(get-date).AddDays(1-$maxPwdAge)
 Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * |
 where {$_.PasswordLastSet -ge $1day}
```

Can someone help me to adjust the script so the results whose password expires within a day put the checkmark 'user must change password' is being set in active directory.

Comment: Which language is this for ? Please edit your tags accordingly

Comment: Why force a password change for every user for which a password change will be forced in 1 day? Sounds kind of contraproductive. With set-Aduser and the -ChangePasswordAtLogon you can achieve this

Comment: Has to do with replication. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Baggio1001 "Has to do with replication" How so? Your replication topology doesn't care whether the password expires now or tomorrow

Comment: If someone forgets to change the password and it will expire in the active Windows session then a lot of background programs witch uses ldap is causing trouble. Hard to explain, but it is very important that the checkmark will be set one day before the password expires. Thanks for helping me @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 0):

This isn't PowerShell but this is what I have in my notes for DOS Batch.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %a in (users.csv) do wmic path Win32_UserAccount WHERE Name='%a' set PasswordExpires=false
```

And I do believe if `PasswordExpires=True` then the user at next logon must change the password.  Additional info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1149)

Comment: That's not what I need. what I need is a continuation of my script:

$maxPwdAge=(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
$1day=(get-date).AddDays(1-$maxPwdAge)
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * |
where {$_.PasswordLastSet -ge $1day}

The script above gives me a list of users whose password expires tomorrow. For those users the checkbox: password must be changed at next logon must be checked. @user4317867

Comment: @Baggio1001 I did some searching and located [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852500/powershell-password-must-change-next-logon-when-password-expires-in-1-day)

Comment: thanks, that gives me the result of users whose password expires tomorrow. the only thing left to do is set user must change password @ next logon in Active Directory..